# Creating a function in R to convert a unit of measurement

Tags: r, function

I would like to create a function that converts a measurement from meters to inches. The goal is to input a measurement (in meters) into the function and it will return a character in US customary units (X ft, X inches). For example,
if you pass the value `1.46` to your function, the output will be the string 
`"4 ft 9 1/2 in"`.

My approach to creating this function was to create a function where it would convert the input from meters to inches, and then create another function where it calculates the remainder, concatenate those 2 numbers into a vector and convert that into a string where it would be in US customary units somehow. I don't know if my logic would work here, but that's all I have so far. This is my code that I've written so far and it incorrectly returns the first number in the vector which is the feet.

```
convert_to_ft <- function(height) {

ft <- ((height * 39.3701) / 12)
}

remainder <- function(height) {

remain <- (((height * 39.3701) / 12) %% 12
}


convert_to_ft_inch <- function(height) {

x <- convert_to_ft(height)
y <- remainder(height)

z <- (as.numeric(x) - as.numeric(y))

result <- c(z, y)
return(result)
}
```

Can someone help me with how I can approach this problem? I feel like I'm tackling this at the wrong angle.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with the `integer` part of the first conversion (meters to feet), substract it from the total number of feet, convert the remain in inches and round it. Finally, paste both results in a string:

```
convert_m_fi <- function(xm){
    xm_ft <- xm * 39.3701 / 12
    xm_ft_int <- floor(xm * 39.3701 / 12)
    xm_inch <- round((xm_ft - xm_ft_int) * 12, 1)
    return(paste(xm_ft_int, "ft", xm_inch, "in"))
}

convert_m_fi(1.46)
#[1] "4 ft 9.5 in"
```